# Magento attribute in title

Tags: magento, attributes, title

Is there an easy way to get the value of a custom attribute to show up in the `<title>` on a Magento product page? I know I can add a custom title via the "Meta information / Meta Title" field. But if it's possible to automatically grab the value of an attribute and add it to the title I'd prefer that.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a module rewriting `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head#getTitle()`. There, you would have to check whether you are on a product page and if yes, add the product attribute there...

A much simpler solution (although it is not as nice as the one above) would be to edit `app/design/frontend/interface/theme/template/page/html/head.phtml` and edit `<title><?php echo $this->getTitle() ?></title>`. To check whether you are on a product page, you could use:

```
if(Mage::registry('current_product')) {
    // add product attribute to title
}
```

How to get your product attribute, you can see [here](http://www.fontis.com.au/blog/magento/displaying-magento-custom-attributes-frontend).

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thank you, @Simon! I'll give it a try tomorrow.